# Unity UpdateExternalTexture from MovieTexture windows crash

Tags: textures, sprites

I'm trying to play a `MovieTexture` object with a `SpriteRenderer` object.
My code is working fine on OSX.

It **crashes** my windows 7 **exported game**, and play mode in **Unity editor** in windows 7.

I am sure the `currentTexture.UpdateExternalTexture()` call is making it crash, but I can't figure out why.

Can anybody explain why this is not working or how to debug it? The Unity log file didn't contain anything that seemed useful, just the message `Crashed.`

Here is what I am using

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class FMAC_VideoPlayer : MonoBehaviour {

public string animationName = "escalator";

MovieTexture movieTexture;
Texture2D currentTexture;
SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
Sprite sprite;

void Start () 
{
    movieTexture = Resources.Load (animationName) as MovieTexture;

    currentTexture = new Texture2D(movieTexture.width, movieTexture.height);
    currentTexture.UpdateExternalTexture(movieTexture.GetNativeTexturePtr());

    spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ();
    sprite = Sprite.Create (currentTexture, new Rect(Vector2.zero, new Vector2(movieTexture.width, movieTexture.height)), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
    spriteRenderer.sprite = sprite;

    movieTexture.Play();
}
}
```

Ideas?

**Update**

I have `Debug.Log()` ed the native texture pointer which prints the pointer address (ex. 556409680 ), so it does not seem to be NULL.

Comment: Are you using any external libraries? If not, sounds like [Unity bug report fun times](https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/bug-reporting) since it works on OS X. Even just the absence of a reasonable error message (*"Crashed." "Thank you Sherlock, I noticed"*) sounds like grounds for a bug report.

Comment: Thank for the response. Where should one report this sort of thing?

Comment: Unity have [a bug reporting guide here](https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/bug-reporting). There's a built-in reporter in the menu, at *Help → Report a bug*.